# How to get an array of Thread::Backtrace::Location related to an exception

Tags: ruby, backtrace

Is there a way to get an array of `Thread::Backtrace::Location` instances attached to an `Exception` instance? If so, how? There are `Kernel#caller_locations` and `Thread#backtrace_locations`, but those are related to the current context or a thread, and not to an arbitrary exception instance. I don't know if those are to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible since ruby v2.1, although full support will probably be ready in v2.2

- Method: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/44170/diff/error.c
- Discussion: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8960